# Find the first defined item in a collection in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, flatmap, scala-cats

Given a collection, `coll: C[A]` and a function `f: A => Option[B]`, what's the idiomatic way in Scala to get the first item in `coll` for which `f` is defined without evaluating the whole collection?

Here's my intended signature:

```
def findFirstDefined[A, B](coll: Traversable[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

A naive approach like `coll.flatMap(f).headOption` would evaluate the whole collection. We can possibly do `coll.view.flatMap(f).headOption` or `coll.collectFirst(Function.unlift(f))` but is there something else either in the standard library or in functional programming literature or in scalaz/cats that would let me do this?

Comment: I would just do `coll.find(f(_).isDefined)` not sure if there is any pretty functional solution.

Comment: `coll.view.flatMap(f).headOption` doesn't compile (monads don't combine), but what's wrong with `coll.collectFirst(Function.unlift(f))`? Seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: @Łukasz You will have to call `f` twice for the found element.  `.collectFirst(Function.unlift(f))` is better in this aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, this seems like a decent solution:

```
def findFirstDefined[A, B](coll: Traversable[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = 
  coll.collectFirst(Function.unlift(f))
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO `coll.collectFirst(Function.unlift(f))` looks like a good solution if you want to use something standard. But it's pretty easy to implement using recursion:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def findFirstDefined[A, B](coll: Traversable[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] =
  if (coll.isEmpty) None
  else {
    val r = f(coll.head)
    if (r.isEmpty) findFirstDefined(coll.tail)(f)
    else r
  }
```

Comment: `collectFirst` doesn't evaluate twice because it uses `applyOrElse`. The scaladoc for `Function.unlift` gives the wrong impression, perhaps.

Comment: @som-snytt I said `f` is evaluated twice in Lukasz's suggestion and mentioned `collectFirst ...` is a better way namely because of `applyOrElse`.

Comment: Yes, I had to figure that part out again, so I mention it for the next person.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `find(p: A => Boolean)` ?

```
def findFirstDefined[A, B](coll: Traversable[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] =
    coll.find(f(_).isDefined).flatMap(f(_))
```

This requires two calls to `f.apply()`, but will only call `apply()` until the first element returning a defined option is found.

Edit: thinking about it (but Victor beat me to that one), `collectFirst()` is a more elegant option as well:

```
coll.collectFirst(Function.unlift(f))
```